# 80387 transistor count

Tags: intel, 80386, 80387

In 1985, Intel released the 80386, a particularly complex and sophisticated microprocessor for its day, consisting of 275,000 transistors, a rather large number for the day.

How many transistors went into the accompanying 80387 floating-point coprocessor?

Comment: 12. Though I did calculate that on my first-gen Pentium.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I’ve wondered about this for a long time — manufacturers don’t seem to communicate FPU transistor counts as readily as CPU counts.

The best I’ve found so far is [a claim on coprocessor.info](https://web.archive.org/web/20070328064115/http://coprocessor.cpu-info.com/index2.php?mainid=html%2Fcopro.php&tabid=4&page=1) that the 80387 contained approximately 120,000 transistors (quite a bit more than the 8087’s 45,000 transistors).

Comment: For comparison, the Cyrix FasMath 83D87 (socket compatible with the 80387) contained about 375,000 transistors. See: Tom Brightman, "Advancing the Standard in Floating-Point Performance", *High Performance Systems*, Vol. 10, No. 11, November 1989, pp. 59-64